# how to read json data indexed object in php

Tags: php, json

Three simple lines of code:

```
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input,true);
print_r($event_json);
```

I have used first 2 lines to convert json data into array in php, and third line prints the following array (a portion I show here):

```
Array
(
    [created] => 1326853478
    [livemode] => 
    [id] => evt_00000000000000
    [type] => charge.succeeded
    [object] => event
    [request] => 
    [pending_webhooks] => 1
    [api_version] => 2014-07-26
    [data] => Array
    (
        [object] => Array
        (
            [id] => ch_00000000000000
            [object] => charge
            [amount] => 100
            [amount_refunded] => 0
```

My question is: How do I echo amount (which is 100) or amount_refunded (which is 0)?

Comment: ignore the json. you've decoded it. it's not json anymore. it's a php data structure now. you access it like you would any OTHER multi-dimensional data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $event_json['data']['object']['amount'];
echo $event_json['data']['object']['amount_refunded'];
```